# Chrome not rendering correct DIV width and Inspector changes layout

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm working with some DIV containers that are supposed to make a site 900 pixels wide, [on this development page](http://mediatorchristineallen.com/dev/).

Chrome (v34, on Mac) is not rendering the page as expected, because it's stretching the site to be about 1020 pixels wide.

When I turn on the code Inspector, the layout is corrected without any input from me.
How can I fix the problem if the Inspector changes the output of the page?

Does anyone else encounter the Inspector problem on my page?

Firefox (v28) and Safari are rendering the page as it should look; all the page content is contained within the 900 pixel width.

Comment: Your div id="page" is 1260px wide on my screen (1080p), what are you expecting?

Comment: @Godinall why does it update automatically on opening the inspector ?

Comment: That's because when your page finishes loading, it will add a class .site to your div id="page", and that class has a max-width=60em, which will override your other max-width defined below, which is 960px. You may need to clean your css.

Comment: The width of the green box is only supposed to be 900 pixels.  Even on my larger 1920 wide monitor, the green box width is correct, but renders wrong in Chrome.  In Chrome, you'll also notice that the Masthead does not match the width of the other content boxes, whereas in Firefox and Safari it does correctly.

This is how the site's content boxes are supposed to look (as seen in Firefox):
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25959526/webdev/mca/firefox-correct-layout.png

In what way can I clean the CSS?

Comment: This issue has been resolved. Clicking on the link OP provided works correctly on Chrome on my Mac.